# As of 2021, what are all common lisp special functions?

Tags: function, common-lisp

Special functions receive this name because they are different from macros and ordinary functions.

Just like macros, special functions do **not** evaluate their inputs. But unlike
macros, they do **not** return Lisp expressions that are to be evaluated. Special
functions provide the primitives on which Lisp is built, such as assignment,
conditionals, and block structure.

In 1989 [1], David S. Touretzky wrote that there were **24** built-in Common Lisp **special functions**:

1. `BLOCK`,
2. `CATCH`,
3. `COMPILER-LET`,
4. `DECLARE`,
5. `EVAL-WHEN`,
6. `FLET`,
7. `FUNCTION`,
8. `GO`,
9. `IF`,
10. `LABELS`,
11. `LET`,
12. `LET*`,
13. `MACROLET`,
14. `MULTIPLE-VALUE-CALL`,
15. `MULTIPLE-VALUE-PROG1`,
16. `PROGN`,
17. `PROGV`,
18. `QUOTE`,
19. `RETURN-FROM`,
20. `SETQ`,
21. `TAGBODY`,
22. `THE`,
23. `THROW`;
24. and, `UNWIND-PROTECT`.

He also said that:

> This list may change with future revisions of the Common Lisp standard.

There was a new release of the book in 2014. However, the information stood the same. Even in the book in 2014, the text starts exactly like the first edition in 1989 with:

> "As of mid-1989, the 24 built-in Common Lisp special functions are:  ...." (page 507).

Not sure if they gave a careful look on this point, if they did, I guess they would have updated the year to be "As of mid-**2014**..."

Thus, as of mid-2021 is the list any different **now** from how it was in 1989?

Source:
[1] - *COMMON LISP: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation*

Comment: googling brings http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababa.htm. I don't think the standard has changed.

Comment: Great. Do you why they use *special forms* instead of *special functions*?

Comment: Do you know*** why ... ?

Comment: the executable lists are called compound forms and have an operator or a lambda expression as first element. The operators are: function, macro, special operator. Thus we have a lambda form, a macro form, a function form and a special form.

Comment: what you have above listed are called in the Common Lisp standard *special operator*. They are not functions and not *special functions* There is no idea of a *special functions* in the standard.

Comment: Ok, thanks @RainerJoswig. The term *special functions* was used in the book from Touretzk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Common Lisp standard (which was published in 1994) there is no concept of a *special function*. The standard defines the concept of a **special operator** and these must not be functions. As Will Ness commented, the *special operators* are listed here in the Common Lisp HyperSpec (which is HTML pages derived from the standard - the original standard is published as a printed doc and a PDF file): [3.1.2.1.2.1 Special Forms](http://lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababa.htm). This is a fixed list -> the standard has no language mechanism provided to the Common Lisp user to add new ones. Though I think that some implementations of Common Lisp have a few additional special operators.

- a **form** is an *object* meant to be evaluated: a symbol, a *compound form* or a self-evaluating object.
- a **compound form**: a list with an *operator* or a lambda expression as the first element: a macro form, a function form, a special form or a lambda form
- a **special form**: a compound form, which has a special operator as its first element
- **special operator**: one of the symbols listed in [chapter 3.1.2.1.2.1](http://lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababa.htm)

Why does the book not use the terminology of the Common Lisp standard? Maybe the author was not aware of it or thought it to be too complex (or too much effort) to update the wording to use the standard wording - which would possibly mean changing a lot of things in the text.

Another useful reference is this late draft of the standard in PDF form: [draft proposed ANSI CL standard](https://franz.com/support/documentation/cl-ansi-standard-draft-w-sidebar.pdf). The draft has basically the same content as the published standard, but is freely available. *The Common Lisp HyperSpec* also has basically the same content, but in a different form.

Answer (score 1):

> > Why does the book not use the terminology of the Common Lisp standard? Maybe the author was not aware of it or thought it to be too complex (or too much effort) to update the wording to use the standard wording - which would possibly mean changing a lot of things in the text.

I believe that the standard used an early form of CLTL, the copyright was "relaxed" to make this possible per Guy Steele Jr.

Comment: Answer does not address question directly, but rather adds a comment